# Classic ASP CStr not working

Tags: regex, asp-classic

I need help with **`Error 800A000D - Type mismatch`** that i am receiving in the sub bellow:

```
<!-- #include file="Regex.asp" -->
<%
Call moverzipado()

Sub moverzipado()
    dim nomeArquivoZip, nomeArquivo 
    nomeArquivo = request("nomeArquivo")
    nomeArquivoZip = NomeArquivo(trim(CStr(nomeArquivo)))&".zip" 'here is the problem
End Sub
```

This is my querystring: **`?nomeArquivo=arquivo.zip`**

this is the Regex.asp include. It is working.

```
<%
Function RegExResults(strTarget, strPattern)

    Set regEx = New RegExp
    regEx.Pattern = strPattern
    regEx.Global = true
    Set RegExResults = regEx.Execute(strTarget)
    Set regEx = Nothing

End Function

Function NomeArquivo(arquivo)
    Set arrResults = RegExResults(arquivo, "(.*)\..*")

    For each result in arrResults
        NomeArquivo = result.Submatches(0)
    Next

    Set arrResults = Nothing
End function

'Response.Write(NomeArquivo("file.exe")) prints "file" here it works.
%>
```

Does anybody know what is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

vbScript is not case sensitive. It appears you have a variable and a function with effectively the same name. Try changing the name of your function or variable.